# Can I get an order confirmation from PayPal Standard without relying on the customer to click "Return to site" from PayPal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

I need to do order processing upon confirmation of payment. Using PayPal Standard, is there a way I can get an order ID (that my site specifies) and a flag for whether the payment is received or not?

It appears that CMS's like Joomla have been able to do what I'm describing, but I haven't been able to find anything in PayPal Documentation that indicates how. Of course, I'm sure the answer is in there, and I will ontinue looking, but if someone could save me some time by pointing me in the correct direction, I would really appriciate it!

Just a little more information, I am developing this site in ASP.NET MVC with C#. I have also been researching PayPal IPN feature, but after talking to other developers in the office, they strongly recommend steering clear of IPN because of it's asynchronous nature.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think IPN is the way to go. I think if they pay the payment might not actually be completed(think of them paying back cheque) and that is where IPN comes in as it will tell you if the payment went through or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to get information from PayPal.  Essentially they break down into two categories, "push" and "pull".

"Push" is when PayPal pushes information to you. There are two ways that PayPal pushes information

1. Information sent in the URL when the customer returns to your site.
2. The IPN notifications.

"Pull" is when you request information from PayPal.  PayPal provides a variety of APIs that you can use to get information about your transactions.  So, for example, you could set up a job that runs every X minutes and asks PayPal for information about any orders that you know were sent to PayPal, but for which you didn't receive information on a return URL.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/transaction_information
https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1372

Comment: I'd love to get more details about option Push option #1. Especially how to configure the return URls